# UI-Router необязательный параметр

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Требуется создать SPA на UI-Router. Имеется, например, три template:

`registration_form1.htm`, `registration_form2.htm` и `statistics.htm`.

Страницы должны получать два параметра, второй из них опциональный. Вот этот момент я не понимаю, как сделать; насколько знаю, как-то можно сделать через `RegExp` (не понял, как). Параметры, для примера, `string`.

Ещё дополнительно:
 Данные должны передаваться между страницами. Например, на `registration_form2.htm` имеется `<input>`, его содержимое должно появляться в отдельном `<div>` на `statistics.htm`, желательно без `$rootScope`.

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но мне кажется, что наоборот, если ты используешь регулярку, то параметр не может быть опциональным. Кроме того, в вопросе я не увидел никаких причин использовать регулярки вместо базового синтаксиса - там точно есть поддержка необязательных параметров.

Comment: вот здесь описаны параметры, я не вижу, что они могут быть опциональными - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing. вот здесь есть длинное обсуждение на английском, честно говоря, не очень понял - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/108

Comment: _**'/user/:id'** - Matches **'/user/bob'** or '/user/1234!!!' or even **'/user/'** but not '/user' or '/user/bob/details'. The second path segment will be captured as the parameter 'id'._

Comment: не понял. т.е. если я хочу передать второй опциональный параметр, я пишу, например, что-то вроде /user/bob&ivan, а затем substring'ом отрезаю всё что после "&" (если "&" не было, значит второго параметра не было)?